# Active Directory view last logged in computers

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, accounts

Is there a way to set a view up/add column for active directory on windows server 2003 under the computers section that tells me when they were last accessed. Just so it's easier when clearing up AD and getting rid of old computers etc from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use the Modified for that purpose.  Typically when a computer account logon or password change occurs, some attribute is changed, which results in the update of the whenChanged attribute.  If a computer is inactive, the Modified column usually does not change.

However, this requires caution as some computer accounts do not change, due to they do not interact with AD as a normal computer account would.  This includes virtual names for clusters, and foreign computer principals such as for NetApps or some Samba servers.

Comment: Thanks. yor right about the modified it doesnt always update but thanks for explanation. =)